# How to get values from JSON in Freemarker

Tags: json, freemarker

So I have a JSON file or html request that looks like this:

```
tuStatus:   
          0:
             references:    […]
             progressBar:   {…}
             changeDeliveryPossible:    false
             arrivalTime:   {…}
             tuNo:  "(here is usually a package number)"
             owners:    […]
             history:   
                     0: 
                        date:   "2021-11-11"
                        time:   "12:52:04"
                        evtDscr:    "Package has been deliverd."
                        address:    
                                 countryName:   "Niederlande"
                                 countryCode:   "NL"
                                 city:  ""
```

I allways want to acess the `history`part at position `0`and check if the package has been deliviered. To check this I need to read out the string at `evtDscr`. If the package has been delivered yet, I want to access the `date` and `time` strings.
How can I acess the variables via freemarker language?

Comment: Depends on how that JSON is exposed to the template. Like `Map`-s and `List`-s? Or as a `String`? Something else?

Comment: Its given by a ```String```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment you say that you get the whole JSON as a single string. So then, assuming you have recent FreeMarker version, you can use `?eval_json`:

```
<#assign someParsed = someString?eval_json>
```

And now you use expressions like `someParsed.tuStatus[0].history[0].evtDscr == "Package has been deliverd."`. (Though I guess the `evtDscr` value is not very reliable... like if somebody fixes the typo in it (should be "deliver**e**d"), the comparison won't work.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its working perfectly for my purpose. And the typo was my mistake so sorry for that.